# Crystal Reports cannot map to new database server

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have performed this process numerous times with other Reports but this one Report is not working as it should.

Essentially, I am trying to point a report at a new server where the stored procedure is EXACTLY the same as on the previous server. I am using the Verify Database functionality to do this. But when I point at the new server and enter parameters, CR prompts me to re-map the fields. This would be only slightly annoying if the Map Fields window actually displayed the returned columns from the new server.

[image]

But, as you can see from the image, even with the 'Match type' unchecked, no columns from the stored procedure display to be mapped. I have clicked on every field in the report but none of them show any columns to map to.

I have also tried changing the Database Location first before trying to verify, but that doesn't make any difference.

Has anybody else seen this? Is there any sort of workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​I found my solution. Kinda dumb, really.
My stored procedure calls another stored procedure. I commented that call out and tried to Verify the Database and it worked.
Apparently Crystal Reports doesn't handle procedures that call other procedures very well when trying to map fields.